# Got wrong column type tinyint and bit

Tags: mysql, jdbc

In MySQL, the column is `tinyint(1)`, but I got `bit` in JDBC when using this code:

```
ResultSet rs=statement.executeQuery(singleSql);
int columnType=rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(1);
```

Comment: If your column is intended to hold TRUE/FALSE values you are better off switching to `bit` datatype. Tinyint(1) holds values between -128 and 127